# Is it possible to detect when a Windows.UI.Xaml Application is closing from within its main page?

Tags: windows, uwp

I am working on an app that needs to know when a UWP application is shutting down from within its MainWindow. Is this possible?

Comment: *"a UWP application"* as in any given application? Or a specific one?

Comment: What type of application are you developing? You mean to get the uwp app closing time from another application, right?

Comment: I would like to know when my app closes so I can to some specific cleanup on an object that lives in the MainWindow.

Comment: The last event an app receives before being terminated is the Suspending event. The app will remain in the suspended state until the user or system decides to terminate it (at which point the app is terminated without being woken). Or the user or system may choose to resume the app, at which point it gets a Resuming event. So save your state in Suspending with the understanding that it may be the last thing you do. If you get a Resuming event, then you know that you are being rewoken and the previous Suspend was a false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clean some object that lives in the MainWindow when the MainWindow is closed, I suggest you could do this in `SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested` event like the following.

Please declare `confirmAppClose` capability.

```
<Package
…… xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
……
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose"/>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested += (s, e) =>
            {
                //clean objects
            };
        }
```

Note that: If you want to submit this app to Store, since confirmAppClose capability is a [restricted capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-submission-options#restricted-capabilities), so you must provide info during the [app submission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-submissions) process in order to be approved to publish the app to the Microsoft Store. You provide this info on the Submission options page of your submission, explaining how your app uses each restricted capability that it declares.

Comment: Note that CloseRequested is not guaranteed to be called. For example, if the app is already suspended and then the user clicks the X button, the app is terminated immediately. Apps should use the Suspending event to save state in anticipation of termination.